# Unity Grid Based Building (Snap to Grid) And Follow Mouse While Snapping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am trying to build a 2d strategy game where you can build on a grid based world and all buildings will have different sizes like 3x3, 2x3 and they will be builded on the grid, based on their sizes. Without making them snap to grid depending on their size, i can make them just follow the mouse and build wherever i want but i need to make them snap to grid depending on their size. How can i achieve this ?[Example Map Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjoBh.png) Alternate image link : https://ibb.co/bQUeae

[EDIT] : Here is the final code down below. Right now i can snap and follow the selected building based on the mouse's position with sending a ray and checking the building grids but still this action does not depend on the building's sizes. Here is a video of current situation. https://youtu.be/fCvsVznJ_4g

```
BuildingScript    

[SerializeField]
private MousePositionChecker mousePositionChecker;

private Transform currentBuilding;
private bool hasPlaced;

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate () {
    if (currentBuilding != null && !hasPlaced)
    {
        //Vector3 m = Input.mousePosition;
        //Vector3 p = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(m);

        //currentBuilding.position = new Vector3(p.x, p.y, 0);

        if(mousePositionChecker.mousePos)
            currentBuilding.position = mousePositionChecker.mousePos.position;

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            hasPlaced = true;
        }
    }
}

public void SetItem(GameObject b)
{
    hasPlaced = false;
    currentBuilding = ((GameObject)Instantiate(b)).transform;
}

MousePositionScript
public Transform mousePos;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(pos, Vector2.zero);
    if (hit != null && hit.collider != null && hit.transform.tag=="BuildArea")
    {
        mousePos = hit.transform;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide code if you already tried anything?

Comment: @PiotrKrankiewicz here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making another script to keep mouse position to check which build area mouse hitting by sending rays and when i select a building i am making it's position to be same with the build area that mouse is hitting.